# how to changing\\ the value in the malloc with

Tags: c, dictionary, segmentation-fault, escaping, game-development

I am creating a game in C programming. The game is there is a player and goal inside the map. The win condition is the player hit goal position. However, when every move of the player, there will be a floor collapse randomly in the map. Therefore, the players will be blocked by the char 'X'.

The thing I need to be done is update the map[i][j] then print the map. Therefore, I am trying to change the char**map by the function "XGenerater". And I used the memcpy the char** map for updating the map in the pRefreshParams. ANd segfault(core dumded).

I tried to placeObj in the chr** map in other function. The 'X' displayed one in the map, after I move the player. Which means the the 'X' is jumping in the map. And it is randomly generate the 'X'

However, my question is how to change the char** map value?

```
char** createMap(int pMapSize[])
{
    int sizeRow = pMapSize[IDX_MAP_NROW];
    int sizeCol = pMapSize[IDX_MAP_NCOL];

    char** map = malloc(sizeRow * sizeof(char*));
    int i = 0;
    
    for(i = 0; i < sizeRow; i++)
        map[i] = malloc(sizeCol * sizeof(char));

    return map;
    }

    void XGenerater(char** map, const int sizeRow, const int sizeCol){
    void initRandom();
    int row, col;

    do
    {
        row = random(0, sizeRow - 1);
        col = random(0, sizeCol - 1);
    
  
    }while (map[row][col] != ' ');
    
    map[row][col] = 'X';
    int moving(void* pRefreshParams[], char cUserInput)
    {
    int gameStatus = GS_NONE_GOAL;
    int aiPlayerCp[ARR_SIZE_OBJ];
    char* aiMapCp[2];
    

    /*int validPosition = FALSE;*/
    
    char** map;
    int *pMapSize, *pGoal, *pPlayer;
    unpackRefreshParams(pRefreshParams, &map, &pMapSize, &pGoal, &pPlayer);

    copyObj(aiPlayerCp, pPlayer);
    /*memcpy(aiMapCp, map, sizeof(char)*ARR_SIZE_OBJ);*/
    copyMap(aiMapCp, map);
    
    
    performMove(aiPlayerCp, pMapSize, cUserInput);
    XGenerater(aiMapCp, pMapSize[IDX_MAP_NROW], pMapSize[IDX_MAP_NCOL]);
    

    copyObj(pPlayer, aiPlayerCp);
    /*memcpy(map, aiMapCp, sizeof(char)*ARR_SIZE_OBJ);*/
    /*copyMap(map, aiMapCp);*/
    
    

    if (pPlayer[IDX_COL] == pGoal[IDX_COL] && pPlayer[IDX_ROW] == pGoal[IDX_ROW])
    {
        refreshMap(pRefreshParams);
        gameStatus = GS_PLAYER_GOAL;
    }
    

    

    return gameStatus;
   }
```

Comment: IMO, the title for the question does not make sense.  In particular, the `\\\` in "how to changing\\ the value in the malloc with" and the 'dangling' "with" confuse me.  The code is not an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  It would make it easier to understand if we could execute your code.

Comment: Lot of strange things. The main one:  as map is an array of pointer to array of char you cannot do memcpy : you must have one memcpy per row.  This is because rows arrays are more likely not contiguous and that map is not a pointer to the first char. If you want to use memcpy you should think about using only a array of char and convert i,j to location in that array.